# jQuery Draggable with Bootstrap Tooltip TypeError: e.$element is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, draggable

I have a draggable element (see the code snippet and click on picture to add pins) which shows a tooltip on mouseover and deletes it on mouseout.

The below code throws tens of errors "TypeError: e.$element is null" in Firefox or "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of null" in Chrome as soon as I start dragging the pin element.

I tried:

```
$('.tooltip').remove();
$('.tooltip').tooltip('destroy');
$('.pin').tooltip('destroy');
```

but none of these solve that.

How can I stop the tooltip errors when dragging the element?

```js
var pic_wrapper = $('#pic_wrapper');

var selected_picture = $('#selected_picture');

selected_picture.on('click', function(e) {
  var pin = $('<div class="pin"></div>');
  x = ((e.offsetX) / $(this).width()) * 100 + "%";
  y = ((e.offsetY) / $(this).height()) * 100 + "%";
  pin.uniqueId();
  pic_wrapper.append(pin);
  pin.css({
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  });
  pin.css({
    left: x,
    top: y
  }).show();
  pin.draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
  });
  pin.on('dragstart', function() {
    pin.css({
      transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)'
    });
  });
  pin.on('dragstop', function(e, ui) {
    x = (ui.position.left / pic_wrapper.width()) * 100 + "%";
    y = (ui.position.top / pic_wrapper.height()) * 100 + "%";
    pin.css({
      left: x,
      top: y
    });
  });
});

pic_wrapper.on('mouseenter', '.pin', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('title', 'tooltip text');
  $(this).tooltip({
    placement: function(context, source) {
      return "right";
    }
  });
  $(this).tooltip('show');
});

pic_wrapper.on('mouseout', '.pin', function(e) {
  $(this).tooltip('destroy');
});
```

```css
#pic_wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px dotted #0099ff;
}

#selected_picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #0099ff;
}

#selected_picture img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.pin {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff4100;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 65, 0, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div id="pic_wrapper">
        <div id="selected_picture">
          <img src="http://www.outline-world-map.com/map-images-original/blank-thin-gray-white-world-map-b9a.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
 $('.tooltip').tooltip('destroy').remove();
```

it should do the trick

I think the reason why you got this error, is that when you do the $('.tooltip').tooltip('destroy') it doesn't remove also all the events linked to the tooltip.

update: It's necessary to update also

```
$(this).attr('title', 'tooltip text');
```

with

```
$(this).attr('data-original-title', 'tooltip text');
```

otherwise it display 2 tooltip!

full JS code:

```
var pic_wrapper = $('#pic_wrapper');

var selected_picture = $('#selected_picture');

selected_picture.on('click', function(e) {
  var pin = $('<div class="pin"></div>');
  x = ((e.offsetX) / $(this).width()) * 100 + "%";
  y = ((e.offsetY) / $(this).height()) * 100 + "%";
  pin.uniqueId();
  pic_wrapper.append(pin);
  pin.css({
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  });
  pin.css({
    left: x,
    top: y
  }).show();
  pin.draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
  });
  pin.on('dragstart', function() {
    pin.css({
      transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)'
    });
  });
  pin.on('dragstop', function(e, ui) {
    x = (ui.position.left / pic_wrapper.width()) * 100 + "%";
    y = (ui.position.top / pic_wrapper.height()) * 100 + "%";
    pin.css({
      left: x,
      top: y
    });
  });
});

pic_wrapper.on('mouseenter', '.pin', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'tooltip text');
  $(this).tooltip({
    placement: function(context, source) {
      return "right";
    }
  });
  $(this).tooltip('show');
});

pic_wrapper.on('mouseout', '.pin', function(e)
{
  $('.tooltip').tooltip('destroy').remove();
});
```

Comment: If I do that, it solves this problem, but then creates another one - now I have 2 tooltips shown: the one I need + another one below, and $(this).tooltip('destroy').remove() actually removes the pin itself, not just the tooltip

Comment: [check this bin](https://jsbin.com/diqibudeme/1/edit?html,css,js,output) this isn't working well? or I missed something?

Comment: No, as soon as I start dragging the pin, it throws lots of those errors

Comment: I don't know what to say, I tried with both firefox and chrome, and I don't have any error in console... :(

Comment: How come? I see tens if not hundreds of them. Is there any way to attach pictures here?

Comment: Ah, now it's ok... weird. However the new problems remains - 2 tooltips are shown! This site has been playing up for the past week - I can't save most of my questions or edits, it throws heaps of errors. I don't know what's wrong here

Comment: can't update anything here, the site's Save always fails to save any edits, I've been trying to update my code for hours now. Your code works. But can you see 2 tooltips if you hover and hold over the pin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173638/discussion-between-margon-and-linuxoid).

Comment: Thanks to @Margon, changing $(this).attr('title', 'tooltip text'); to $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'tooltip text'); solved the 2 tooltips issue. And lots of thanks for him for suggesting $('.tooltip').tooltip('destroy').remove(); - this solved the original problem.